# Language support on android

Tags: java, android, internationalization, android-assets

I want to type in different languages in android other than **English** like **Hebrew** by providing `ttf` files. Are there any in build `API`'s so I can use that?

Answer (score 5):

There is an example on how to use custom typefaces in the [API Demos](http://developer.android.com/guide/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/Typefaces.html). That said, you may not ***need*** to. [This article](http://www.forbes.com/2008/09/25/font-android-g1-tech-wire-cx_ew_0926font.html?feed=rss_technology) seems to indicate that the default font (Droid) probably contains all the necessary characters for (at least) the target markets for Android.

Other than that, the developer site has [pretty good documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/resources-i18n.html) on how to "internationalize" an application.

Answer (score 1):

You can localize you application by using ttf files

Here is the sample code to start with

Create a folder under **assets** with name "fonts". Copy your language file (ex: mylang.ttf).

Load this file using the following code:

```
Typeface myfont;
myfont=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/mylang.ttf");
TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
textview.setText(R.string.my_textview);
    textview.setTypeface(myfont);
```

In `string.xml`, give **"some language string"** for `my_textview`.

Now you can see your language text in android device/emulator.

Answer (score 0):

there are no built-in features for using *.ttf files. to use different languages look here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/resources-i18n.html#AlternateResources
http://almondmendoza.com/2009/01/28/force-localize-an-application-on-android/

first link in android dev guide about making resources internalizable, second - how to switch locale in app.

Comment: There is so "built-in features for using *.ttf files". See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look here: http://varunmc133.blogspot.com/2009/10/android-internationalization.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.